# I need to "cat" a bunch of files in different locations

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have around 120 folders with sub directories but they all contain one file, a "download.txt" file that is created in its own directory bu 120 scripts executing in parallel.

I want to make all these scripts share the same file, but I need to merge or "cat"(I believe `cat` can be used for this purpose)them first.

What would be the best way do to this in bash/shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the files are closed by writers:

```
find root_dir -name download.txt -exec cat {} \; > merged_download.txt
```

where the `root_dir` is the path to the parent of those 120 directories.

Answer (score 2):

If these txt files are in same folder structure, such as always in folder1/folder2/download.txt, then you can run a simple one:

```
cat */*/download.txt > merged_download.txt
```